# How to change the color of buttons in Alert in Ionic2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Is it possible to change the color of buttons of Alert (Ok, Cancel) in Ionic2? Can we use `cssClass` property to give color to buttons?

```
.buttonCss{
    button{
        color:#e74c3c !important;
    }
}
```

The above code gives the same color to the both Ok and Cancel buttons like the below image
[image]

But I need to get the following result(Both button shoulb in in different color),
[image]

Any help is appreciated...!

### Edit 1: Added `showAlert()` function

```
    showAlert(title, message, yesHandler, noHandler, caller) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: title || "Please Confirm",
        message: message,
        cssClass:'buttonCss',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Exit',
                handler: () => yesHandler(caller)
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => noHandler(caller)
            }
        ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

Comment: @sebaferreras , Can you help me with this?

Comment: You can only tag a user when that user added a comment/answer on that post (I did not receive any notification because of your comment, I've seen this post only because I entered from the home page). Regarding your question, please take a look at my answer and let me know if it works on your end :)

Comment: @sebaferreras, thanks for you suggestion, I will keep it in mind :) .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1) First option, just using a class for the alert, and a css style rule for each button**

```
showAlert(title, message, yesHandler, noHandler, caller) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: title || "Please Confirm",
        message: message,
        cssClass:'buttonCss',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Exit',
                handler: () => yesHandler(caller)
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => noHandler(caller)
            }
        ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

And then:

```
.buttonCss {

    button.alert-button:nth-child(1){
      color: red;
    }

    button.alert-button:nth-child(2){
      color: green;
    }
}
```

This way the first button (`nth-child(1)`) will be `red` and the second button (`nth-child(2)`) will be `green`.

**2) Second option, using a class for the alert, and adding the `cssClass` property to each button, in order to use that custom class on each button**

```
showAlert(title, message, yesHandler, noHandler, caller) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: title || "Please Confirm",
        message: message,
        cssClass:'buttonCss',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Exit',
                cssClass: 'exit-button',
                handler: () => yesHandler(caller)
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'cancel-button',
                handler: () => noHandler(caller)
            }
        ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

And then:

```
.buttonCss {

    button.alert-button.exit-button{
      color: red;
    }

    button.alert-button.cancel-button{
      color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. You helped me again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each button a class, then when assigning a class to each button, you can change the colour of each individual button. Also you can add hover effects to change the colour on hover as well.

Comment: This is for a mobile application. Please check my updated question

Comment: like i said in the answer, you will need to give each button an id or a class and define the css for each.

Comment: using cssClass?

Answer (score 0):

you have options to add custom class for button using `cssClass`

```
showAlert(title, message, yesHandler, noHandler, caller) {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: title || "Please Confirm",
    message: message,
    cssClass:'buttonCss',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Exit',
            handler: () => yesHandler(caller)
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            cssClass: 'customClass',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => noHandler(caller)
        }
    ]
});
alert.present();
```

}

In Css:

```
.customClass{
  color:#e74c3c !important;
 }
```

Comment: let me check that

Comment: use cssClass instend of type

Comment: U can add ::ng-deep .customClass{
  color:#e74c3c !important;
 }